# lightbox plugin that supports image url's

Tags: looking-for-a-script, plugin

I'm looking for a lightbox plugin that supports image url's, I mean a particular image or image gallery to have a specific url that I can  share it.
For example : www.mysite.com/imageurl.html

Comment: Lightbox plugins are typically Javascript, however, you appear to be asking about a server-side script - are you looking for a content management system plugin, an ASP/PHP script, or ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're going to find a "lightbox" that does this. The entire point of those implementations is to be an overlay; they're subservient to the overall document and *that's* the URL that gets referenced.

Permalinks are most often reserved for more gallery-style implementations, the difference being that those are generally embedded within the page. A recent one I've used in [TN3Gallery](http://www.tn3gallery.com/examples/default/); there's a standalone script as well as a WordPress-integrated plugin. The examples on their site don't make use of the permalink feature(it's optional), but the URLs come out looking like `http://example.com/gallery/#tn3=album-name/image-name`for example.